# Regex issue with capturing group PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have been looking around for a while and haven't been able to find what I'm looking for or perhaps I just don't know enough to know what I am looking for...

I have a situation where I want to capture and expression surrounded by parentheses that is a alphabetic character between 1 and 5 characters long. This is not difficult. Next I want to exclude the exact string (AP) from my search.

I am using regex101 and I appear to be getting a match on the string I want to get (or the space right before it) but the match is only returning ''' and not the full (EXC) that I want. Here is the regex I have currently:

```
/((?=\(\D{1,5}\)))(?:.(?!AP))/gism
```

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction; I will provide more information if necessary.

Comment: The regex works on regex101 but not PHP? Post your PHP usage and/or regex101 link. First guess, there is no `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: chris is right, use preg_match_all instead of preg_match as a workaround

Comment: No the expressiondoesnt match the whole expression I want it to, it says it matches but not the right term. in regX101 the Match information reads: 1. [28-28] ''

Comment: so I got the answer from a consultant but still dont know why it works, best answer to who ever tells me why this expression works:    /(\(\D{1,5}\))(?<!\(AP\))/gism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a comparison of the regex you first had, and the regex that works (spaces added):

```
/((?= \(\D{1,5}\) )) (?:  .(?!AP ))/gism
/((     \D{1,5}   )) (?<!  (  AP ))/gism
```

Your first pattern will match the opening parenthesis when they are around something nonnumeric that doesn't start with `ap`. Look arounds do not match characters, keep in mind. (The dot is the only character that isn't in a look around.)

The other pattern removes the literal parenthesis: `\(` and `\)`. It also removed the look ahead `?=` so that you are actually capturing something. The last part of the regex is a negative look behind. In this case, all it does is prevent the pattern from matching a `p` when the thing it matches ends in `ap`.

I cannot explain why the second pattern has so many unnecessary parenthesis, however. This is equivalent:

```
/(\D{1,5})(?<!AP)/gism
```